# Questin About use unity for AOP

Tags: .net, unity-container, aop

```
    IUnityContainer Container = new UnityContainer();
    Container.RegisterType<MyService>();
    container.AddNewExtension<Interception>()
             .Configure<Interception>()
             .SetInterceptorFor<MyService>(new InterfaceInterceptor());
```

The Error is:System.ArgumentException: **The type MyService is not interceptable.**

The Class of MyService do not implement any interface or class.
How Can I write it?

Answer (score 4):

you should write an interface for the class:

```
public interface IMyService
{
    // place MyService method signatures here
}
```

Make your service implement the interface:

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    // place MyService method implementation here
}
```

And then register the service by using the interface and implementation:

```
Container.RegisterType<IMyService, MyService>();
```

Finally initialize interception for the service:

```
.SetInterceptorFor<IMyService>(new InterfaceInterceptor());
```